# Zend_Locale_Format number_format number does not work

Tags: zend-framework, format, locale

i have code like this:

```
    $options = array(
                    'number_format' => '#.##'
            );
    $value = '22155000000000000048';
    $result = Zend_Locale_Format::getNumber($value, $options);
    var_dump($result);
```

receive: 22155000000000000048

suppose: 22155000000000000048.00

even `'number_format' => '#.00'` not helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use toNumber() instead of getNumber(). And correct format is '#0.00'

```
$options = array(
                'number_format' => '#0.00'
        );
$value = '22155000000000000048';
$result = Zend_Locale_Format::toNumber($value, $options);
var_dump($result);
```